# Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, no array or string given in class-wp-hook.php:308

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, hook

I am getting this error while viewing any of my WordPress page or post “

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, no array or string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:308 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php(3049): do_action(‘wp_head’) #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-canvas.php(17): wp_head() #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include(‘E:\xampp\htdocs…’) #5 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once(‘E:\xampp\htdocs…’) #6 E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require(‘E:\xampp\htdocs…’) #7 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 308

“

I was basically making a plugin. The plugin works fine in live server or website. But in localhost, I am getting that fatal error and am unable to view any post or page. I am unable to debug or catch the problem because I don’t know which callback function and argument I need to update? May I get solution about what callback function and argument I need to update?

Comment: Just wondering if anybody can reply....